# Time conversion using pytz isn't accurate

Tags: python, pytz

I am using the `'2014.2'` version of `pytz`. I am converting `Asia/Kuwait` timezone i.e local time to `UTC` time using the following process:

```
>>> from_date = "2014/05/06 17:07"
>>> from_date = dateutil.parser.parse(from_date)
>>> utc=timezone('UTC')
>>> from_date = from_date.replace(tzinfo=timezone('Asia/Kuwait')).astimezone(utc)
>>> from_date
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 6, 13, 55, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> from_date.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S" )
'May 06 2014 13:55:00'
```

The actual UTC time was `May 06 2014 14:06:00` which I found in: http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_UTC.aspx Why `pytz` is not exactly converting to the actual time. As you can see there is a time difference between `10-11 minutes.`

Comment: `est = timezone('UTC')`? That's UTC, not EST..

Comment: And the actual UTC time is May 06 2014 14:07:00, more likely. :-)

Comment: Kuwait used to have a UTC offset of +3:12:00 way back when (1950?). The timezone object defaults to that. As Martijn's answer points out, you need to localize it

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry that was a typo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `datetime.replace()` with `pytz` timezones. From the [`pytz` documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic):

> Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones.

The reason it doesn't work is that `pytz` timezones include historical data and `datetime` is not equipped to handle these.

Use the dedicated `timezone.localize()` method instead:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> from_date = "2014/05/06 17:07"
>>> from_date = dateutil.parser.parse(from_date)
>>> from_date = timezone('Asia/Kuwait').localize(from_date).astimezone(timezone('UTC'))
>>> from_date
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 6, 14, 7, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> from_date.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S" )
'May 06 2014 14:07:00'
```

The `timezone.localize()` method applies a timezone to a naive `datetime` object correctly.

Comment: Thanks man. `localize()`, it is.